# Наследование дружбы классов

Tags: c++

Можно-ли как-то предоставить доступ к protected переменным класса, дочерним классам класса-друга?

Ну, вот такой вот казус:

```
class foo
{
    friend class bar;
    int i;
public:
    void hello() { i = 0;/*OK*/ };
};
class bar
{
public:
    void hello(foo *f) { f->i = 0;/*OK*/ };
};
class baz : public bar
{
public:
    void hello(foo *f) { f->i = 0;/*ERROR*/ };
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как решить эту проблему.

*P.S. Вот такого типа дочерних классов будет около двадцати*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя. Другом класса является только тот класс, что явно указан в списке друзей. Поэтому, Вам придётся либо перечислять все классы явно, либо же добавить в `bar` функции, которые позволят дочерним классам, работать с закрытыми членами `foo`.

В любом случае, злоупотреблять `friend` не стоит, скорее всего у Вас проблема в дизайне, и задача может быть решена куда проще и элегантнее вообще без `friend`.

Comment: _"злоупотреблять friend не стоит"_ вот поэтому и спрашиваю. А вот за _"добавить в bar функции"_, спасибо за идею, выручил(-а).

Answer (score 0):

Вам требуется предоставить доступ к закрытым членам класса извне с помощью функций `get/set`. Примерно так:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int i;
public:
    void set_i(int i) { this->i = i; }
    int get_i() const { return i; }

public:
    void hello() { i = 0;/*OK*/ };
};

class bar
{
public:
    void hello(foo *f) { f->set_i(0);/*OK*/ };
};
class baz : public bar
{
public:
    void hello(foo *f) { f->set_i(0);/*OK*/ };
}
```

Comment: Не, у меня это не работает, собственно, и такой вариант тоже пытался использовать, но и protected члены класса не доступны. А чел, который первый, уже решил мою проблему _("добавить в bar функции, которые позволят дочерним классам, работать с закрытыми членами foo.")_

Comment: Там нет наследования от `foo`, Ваш код нерабочий.

Comment: Да, уже после ответа, и сам подумал, что ТС нужен доступ к закрытым членам извне, а не через наследников. Ответ исправил.